# cant remove .text. using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string:

```
"the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed."
```

I am trying to remove `".this text needs to be removed."` using Python.

I have tried multiple ways to do this, mainly consisting of `\w+(\..*\.)`, but it does not work.  I need a general way to remove this last part, since the text is different per file, so something like `re.sub('\.this text needs to be removed\.', '', string)` will not work for me.

Comment: stack overflow is not showing my escaped dot, i am literally looking to capture from the first dot then anything all the way up to the last dot point again.  In the above example the first dot and the last dot are escaped they are just not showing up that way

Comment: Dot is a special character in Markdown (for enumerations), so using \. it in plain-text causes just the dot being shown. To fix this either use backticks for code (as is the case for your question, now edited) or escape the backslash itself when you need it in plain-text.

Comment: To improve your question it might help if you are a little more concrete about what you tried, and show both some working and non-working in-/output.

Comment: This question needs a huge clarification on whether you simply 'need to remove [stringtext past a dot]' or to 'capture from the first dot up to the last dot'.  Until this is clear, you cannot expect a good implementation solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should look like this:

```
re.sub(r'\.[^.]*?\.$', '', someString)
```

This will ensure that `re.sub` only matches the text between periods at the end of the string. Without the `$`, it will match any set of matching periods in the string.

**EDIT**

If you want to capture *everything* between dots: `\..*\.`

Comment: Quote from the question: "something like, `re.sub('.this text needs to be removed.', '', string)` will not work for me"

Comment: @NiklasB.: It works absolutely fine for me, I had just assumed that the OP had forgotten to escape his periods.

Comment: What OP meant by that is that he cannot hardcode the text between the dots because it might be different. But yeah, it could be misinterpreted, so I'd remove my downvote if you'd edit the answer, because it's locked.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with abhijit, why not just use the string functions?  For example:

```
s1="the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed."
s2=s1.replace(".this text needs to be removed.","")
```

While regular expressions are very powerful, the methods on string objects are often optimized for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, you can achieve what you want with:

```
str = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed.'
str = str.split('.this text needs to be removed.', 1)

print str[0] /* it prints "the quick brown fox jumped over the moon" */
```

Comment: this code is horribly un-re-usable. Even if the string stayed static (which I doubt it would), the :40 is hard-coded, error-prone, and not universal.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the `.`, and made some other mistakes. This should work:

```
s = "the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed."
s = re.sub("\..*\.", "", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with regex simply use sub.

```
>>> re.sub("\.this text needs to be removed\.","","the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed.")
'the quick brown fox jumped over the moon'
```

But task as simple as this can be done with Python string functionality

```
>>> "the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed.".replace(".this text needs to be removed.","")
'the quick brown fox jumped over the moon'
```

And a generic way to remove the last sentence would be

```
>>> re.sub("\.[^\.]+","","the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed.")
'the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.'
```

And without regex would be

```
>>> ''.join("the quick brown fox jumped over the moon.this text needs to be removed.".rsplit('.',2)[:-2])
'the quick brown fox jumped over the moon'
>>>
```

Comment: Quote from the question: "something like, `re.sub('.this text needs to be removed.', '', string)` will not work for me"

Comment: @Niklas, see my update. OP edited the epilogue later after all the below posters posted their answer

Comment: @NiklasB.: If a poster updates a Question/Answer within 5 mins of an editing it does not appear in the history. Any way either I missed it or it was not their with the original post, so point of arguing on that :-)